# While running a project from Git on my pycharm, showing some error

Tags: python, django

Every Django project that I'm trying from git is showing the same error. Although I install all the requirements it is still showing error while I try to run the server.

This is the command which I try to execute:

[image: 1]

And this is the final error:

[image: 2]

***And here is the error.***

```
G:\Study\Python\Django Project\Airline-reservation-django-master>py manage.py makemigration
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\vivek\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 367, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\vivek\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 341, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Users\vivek\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 27, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\vivek\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models(all_models)
  File "C:\Users\vivek\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 199, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "C:\Users\vivek\Python\Python38-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "G:\Study\Python\Django Project\Airline-reservation-django-master\Airline\models.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User
  File "C:\Users\vivek\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\models.py", line 4, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "C:\Users\vivek\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\base_user.py", line 52, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
RuntimeError: __class__ not set defining 'AbstractBaseUser' as <class 'django.contrib.auth.base_user.AbstractBaseUser'>. Was __classcell__ propagat
ed to type.__new__?
```

Answer (score 0):

it is because it provide its own virtual environment and in that environment not all the requirements install try to install all the requirements again to solve this problem from pycharm

```
the only thing you have to do is you have to specify your python interpreter and install your require software on that
```

Comment: Actually I have already set the python interpreter for that, but still no progress.

Comment: use 'pip freeze' command in pycharm and make sure requirements are installed

Comment: yes, it is showing me all the installed file that is required to run the project.

Comment: there are two reason if you got this error you have wrong verson of python or django or you havent installed djnago

Comment: are you sure about "python3" because it is showing the error that python3 is not recognized

Comment: which os you are using ubantu, windows or mac

Comment: windows operating system

Comment: run 'django-admin' in pycharm terminal hope you didn't get any error

Comment: already done these things and everything is fine, I don't think python interpreter is creating the problem it must be something else

Comment: you are overriding an absract base user so there is a provlem in that have you specifield auth_user_model in settings.py

Comment: In which variable

Comment: send me a your projects user model in the question

Comment: https://github.com/HariPrasathHari/Airline-reservation-django

Comment: this is the project which I'm trying to run.

Comment: Why did you write py  manage.py makemigration instead of python    manage.py makemigrations

Comment: in you project settings.py second line on comments django version is 1.10 so it is basically to bit old and not supported by python 3 that is the reason django version is too old try to upgrade to django 3.0.8 run make a new project